# Reversing a number

Tags: entities

I am trying to use a form field to add a number to itself, reversed.
Such as number input into field 15729 which would be added to 92751 and the result displayed.  Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) to use PHP to calculate the reverse of the number.

> Computed Field is a very powerful field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

(heres a snippet from, http://www.phpmoot.com/php-reverse-number/ on how to reverse a number in php - there are lots of different ways to do, just google it)

```
<?php
$num=65410205; // 65410205
$revnum=0;
do{
 $revnum=($revnum *10)+($num % 10);
 $num=(int)($num / 10 );
}while($num>0);
echo $revnum;  // 50201456
?>
```

Then add the two fields together with a Computed field.

Edit: didn't see your tag for javascript, you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351825/reverse-decimal-digits-in-javascript#answer-6351965 to reverse the number, then simple JS logic to output the values in the textboxes you want... but using JS for this is not a drupal solution it's pure JS which is slightly off-topic.

Comment: That code is overly complicated. Just use [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php).